# Can SASS OLAP design be stored in GIT repository?

Tags: sql-server, git, repository, ssas, olap

Can you design/develop SSAS OLAP with GIT repository?

If you're designing/developing OLTP database you may store every table/view/procedure/function and so on in separerate SQL file and commit every change to GIT repository.

Can you work the same way while designing facts and dimensions for OLAP and store every change to GIT repository?

Do you know any tutorials for OLAP + GIT?

Comment: Sounds like the ever lasting discussion on SourceControl / VersionControl on databases. There are some commercial products out there. If you want to do it yourself there are many suggestions to be found by Google. All you need to do for that is script your SSAS cubes in SSMS. Is that possible? Sure it is! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141338/is-it-possibile-to-remotely-process-an-ssas-cube-throgh-script or https://dataonwheels.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/simple-batch-script-to-generate-xmla-and-deploy-ssas-db/

Comment: Script for scripting OLAP into XML file is a kind of solution (thank you) - if only dumped XML is not to messy and a diffs between commits are in fact readable. So while building OLAP you cannot work with source code but all job is done visually?